# pyinstaller stops python from reading from script directory

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, configparser

I have this block of code that works in python script form but when I package the script to an exe using pyinstaller it always results in the program saying the config file can't be found. I put the `config.ini` in the same folder as the exe file.

```py
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
configComplete = True
configExists = False
try:
    open(os.path.join(sys.path[0],'config.ini'))
    config.read(os.path.join(sys.path[0],'config.ini'))
    destination = config['server']['ServerAddress']
    key = config['server']['ApiKey']
    configExists = True
except KeyError:
    configComplete = False
except FileNotFoundError:
    try:
        open(expanduser('~/.config/octoprint-cli.ini'))
        config.read(expanduser('~/.config/octoprint-cli.ini'))
        destination = config['server']['ServerAddress']
        key = config['server']['ApiKey']
        configExists = True
    except KeyError:
        configComplete = False
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have python currently installed to test this on my machine, but typically when I am looking for a file that's relative to the python file location it's preferable to use:

```py
import os

CONFIG_FILE_PATH = f"{os.path.dirname(__file__)}{os.sep}config.ini"


if os.path.exists(CONFIG_FILE_PATH): # If the file already exists
    config.read(CONFIG_FILE_PATH) # Read it

else: # If a config file does not exist
    # Either throw error or create fresh config
```

This code is an OS agnostic way of looking for a file in the same directory as the python file and the catching doesn't necessarily throw an error unless you want it to.

See if that works with pyinstaller, as I believe when I last used it this worked.